# Xamarin Forms - debug prism module

Tags: prism

Hy,

i have a Xamarin Prism application basically created with the PRISM Template Pack.

My modules are separated dlls.
I want to debug the modules code. So i add the source page in my shell applications visual studio window and set breakpoints.
When i run my application and open Debug-Window-Module dialog, i can see that my module status is "symbols loaded in VM". 
So everything looks fine to me.

BUT the debugger doesn´t stop on my breakpoints.
Can anyone tell me what i can do to have debugging?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Check out the solution submitted by @Breeze Liu - MSFT for this [similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48374187/xamarin-forms-uwp-unable-to-debug-shared-code/48414122#48414122).

It is possible that you need to edit the .csproj file of the shared project to include the following:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
   <DebugType>Full</DebugType>
</PropertyGroup>
```