# Xamarin Forms UWP - Unable To Debug Shared Code

Tags: c#, debugging, xamarin.forms, uwp, xamarin.uwp

I've recently started having this issue for the latest version of Xamarin Forms with .NET standard 2.0 as the code sharing strategy.

I am able to place a breakpoint and stop in any code that lives in the UWP project but if I place a breakpoint in the shared DLL code, the breakpoint turns from solid red to a red outlined circle filled in with white. When I put my mouse over the breakpoint, it says the symbols have not been loaded for that location.

What am I doing wrong to be able to debug the shared code for Xamarin Forms UWP? Android and iOS work.

Comment: Remove bin folder and try again, maybe it’s not rebuilding with correct reference

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> What am I doing wrong to be able to debug the shared code for Xamarin Forms UWP? Android and iOS work.

It's known [issue](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/16160/cannot-debug-code-from-referenced-net-standard-lib.html) in Visual Studio. Currently, there is a workaround that you could refer.

```
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugType>Full</DebugType>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Place the above code in the .NET Standard Library csproj file.

Comment: I added this to the .NET Standard library and it worked. Thank you so much!

Comment: for me this does not work on Xamarin.Android projects (when trying to debug .net standard 2.0 library). Any other ideas?

Comment: Also delete all the files at C:\Users\username.domain\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio. They are just temp files with potentially major impacts when you really need to clean all files, especially when you are trying to change build parameters.

Answer (score 3):

Select the UWP project as startup project and then open `Build` menu and choose `Configuration Manager`. There make sure that the .NET Standard library is selected in the **Build** column.

If that does not help, delete the **bin** and **obj** folder from both shared library and UWP project and try again. Sometimes also uninstalling the UWP app from your PC manually helps.

Comment: Also just tried this and it did not work. Same behavior has before. Build was selected already for the .NET standard library.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it helps, but under `Debug`,`Options`,`Debugging (General)` I would disable the `Enable Just My Code` option