# how to debug xamarin code in visual studio 2017

Tags: .net, xamarin, uwp

I am creating a project on UWP with Xamarin form but I am unable to debug code??

I am creating a Login.xaml page and code on design part is :-
`<Button Text="Login" Clicked="OnNextPage" BackgroundColor="Yellow" />`
and Login.xaml.cs file:- I tried to calling button click event:-
[you can see in below image:-](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4juK7.png)
But breakpoint not hitting when click on button.

Comment: Are you trying to debug on your local computer or another device? Also, check to make sure you're actually in debug mode and not release in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the same issue here:
[Xamarin Forms UWP - Unable To Debug Shared Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48374187/xamarin-forms-uwp-unable-to-debug-shared-code/48414122#48414122)

Try the workaround from @Nico Zhu - MSFT to place the following code in the .NET Standard Library csproj file.

```
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugType>Full</DebugType>
</PropertyGroup>
```